# AngularJS options with a simple_form checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, checkbox, simple-form

How does one assign ng-model to a checkbox in simple_form? I have tried adding it like this:

```
=f.input :super_admin , label: false, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false, as: :boolean,:input_html=>{"ng-model"=>"superadmincbx"}
```

but my ng-hide does not work.

```
%span{"ng-hide"=>"superadmincbx"}
```

I'm also using the Batarang and checking/unchecking the checkbox does not trigger the corresponding changes in the scoped item.

However, in my controller, if I add

```
$scope.superadmincbx = true;
```

it get's picked up by the checkbox(it's checked) and ng-hide works. What am I not seeing/doing wrong?

Comment: ng model's value is not set by the initial html state.

Comment: hmmm, sorry, but what does that mean? I have the same code for select:  =f.association :survey_type, as: :select,:input_html =>{"ng-model"=>"survey_type"} which works fine.

Comment: Works fine for radio buttons, maybe you should try this. Or the problem is with scope try nameOfForm['resorce[superadmincbx]'] (not tested)